# Allowing a user to input an amount of money with or without a dollar sign

Tags: c++

Simple question, probably pretty dumb, but I can't find anything on it anywhere. Essentially, the user needs to enter a monetary value (double variable). This can be done with or without a dollar sign, and it should still store the digit input.

The only semi-solution I have found is this:

```
double money;
char dollarSign;
std::cin >> dollarSign >> money;
```

This allows me to input, say, $8 or $8.50 just fine, but of course, when I try to input the money amount, it will take the first digit as a char and skip to a new line, then taking the money input. Is there a way to circumvent this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to "circumvent this issue". Read the input into a plain `std::string`, and check it for correctness. Write the code to actually strip off the leading and trailing whitespace, and the leading dollar sign, if there is one. Take what's left, verify that it contains only, and only, one or more digits, followed by an optional period and two digits. And only if all these conditions are met, use the valid string to construct a `std::istringstream` and use `>>` to extract it into your `money`.  Mission accomplished.

Comment: Why not read as a string, and then attempt to parse that string afterwards (like checking if the first character is a `'$'` or not)?

Answer (score 3):

You might do this:

```
char input;
std::cin >> input; // accepting anything but spaces
double ammount;

if (input != '$')
   std::cin.putback(input);

std::cin >> ammount;

if (!std::cin) 
    std::cerr << "Wrong input input should be $12.34 or $ 12.34 or 12.34";
```

Comment: I didn't know cin.putback(variableName) existed. That's quite useful. Solved my problem. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You take the money as a string.

```
string s;
cin>>s;
if(s[0]=='$')
    s=s.substr(1); //strips of the leading dollar
double money = atof(s);`
```